# Finding a user in the REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using MS Project online, and I have a "ProjectOwnerName" and a "ProjectOwnerID"

I want to find the associated email address for this user.
Now I can match on name, but it's not robust. So I would prefer to use this ProjectOwnerID. But I cannot find what it connects to.

```
https://......sharepoint.com/sites/..../_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=startswith(Title,%20%27John%27)
```

Using PowerQuery to explore the API, I see tables within tables within tables. In the little that I have managed to explore, I cannot find a matching key for "ProjectOwnerID"

Where can I find a ERD or a shortcut to exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following api to get the email

> https://site_url/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$select=Title,EMail&$filter=startswith(Title,%20%27John%27)

You can also use

> https://site_url/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Email&$filter=startswith(Title,%20%27John%27)

You can also try looking at _api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor ....

Comment: Thanks but my question is more around the GUID style field called `ProjectOwnerID`. And what that field represents and links to.

Comment: you can pass the the ProjectOwnerID in Filter 
example ProjectOwnerID = 82

https://site_url/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$select=EMail&$filter ID eq 82

Comment: I'm just getting an error `<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'ProjectOwnerID' does not exist.</m:message>` The ProjectOwnerID as a fieldname won't exist in the SharePoint list. It will be under a different name. But what?

Comment: what is the api that you are using ?

Comment: https://....sharepoint.com/sites/..../_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$select=ProjectOwnerID

Comment: You cannot select column which is not in SiteUserInfoList. SiteUserInfoList can only return you Properties like 
ID , Title , Email , department , login Name etc

Comment: I know that. That is what I am asking. What is this  ProjectOwnerId referring to?

Comment: From where you got the ProjectOwnerID ? I can only assume as its a custom column name. It could be the ProjectOwner column in SharePoint of type person. With person type we have Id like ProjectOwnerID which is the person ID in that site.